# The handling of numbers in Python

Tags: python

guys. I'm new to Python and I got a simple question about the handling of numbers in this language that I couldn't figure out. It's a word guessing game that I was trying to build.

```
answer = "SOPHIA"
guess = ""
attempt = 3


guess = input("TYPE YOUR ANSWER: ")

while guess != answer and attempt > 1 :
    attempt = attempt - 1
    print("WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING: " + str(attempt))
    guess = input("TYPE YOUR ANSWER AGAIN: ")

if attempt == 0:
    print("NO MORE ATTEMPT REMAINING.")
else:
    print("CORRECT ANSWER.")
```

And when I executed the above code, the outcome was

```
TYPE YOUR ANSWER: Leon
WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING: 2
TYPE YOUR ANSWER AGAIN: Raphael
WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING: 1
TYPE YOUR ANSWER AGAIN: Michael
CORRECT ANSWER.
```

I tried to include the numbers in int() but got the same result.

After giving a wrong answer three times, I should have got "NO MORE ATTEMPT REMAINING." while I got "CORRECT ANSWER.". Did I misunderstand the working of numbers in Python. I know the answer should be simple but I still can't get it. Could anyone tell me where I got wrong?

Thank you, guys.

Comment: You might want to check what value `attempt` has when you exit the while loop.

Comment: Your while loop is exited after 2 loops, with attempt == 1

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python and everything to do with logic. Think about what happens if `attempt` is equal to 1 and you compare `attempt > 1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change your loop condition to this:

```
while guess != answer and attempt > 0:
```

In your previous version

```
while guess != answer and attempt > 1:
```

You stop loop when `attempt=1` and that's why this condition `if attempt == 0:` never true.

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
while guess != answer and attempt >= 1
```

Actually your code, in case of wrong answer third time, isn't changing attempt variable to 0 and attempt variable remains 1 so else block is being executed

Answer (score 1):

I am also new but i think it is the logic which has issue. Can u try with 
while guess != answer and attempt > 0 :

Answer (score -1):

```
TYPE YOUR ANSWER: ken
WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING: 2
TYPE YOUR ANSWER AGAIN: seth
WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING: 1
TYPE YOUR ANSWER AGAIN: cue
1
CORRECT ANSWER.
```

I ran your program with a simple print statement above your conditional and this is what I got. My guess is that your looping conditional is wrong. Here is what I would do:

```
answer = "SOPHIA"
guess = ""
attempt = 3

while attempt > 0 :
    guess = input("TYPE YOUR ANSWER: ")
    if guess == answer:
        break
    attempt = attempt - 1
    print("WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING: ")


if attempt == 0:
    print("NO MORE ATTEMPT REMAINING.")
else:
    print("CORRECT ANSWER.")
```

That way, you get the number of iterations you want. Otherwise, if you just change the conditional to:

```
while guess != answer and attempt > 0:
```

Then you get this edge case:

```
TYPE YOUR ANSWER: ken
WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING: 
TYPE YOUR ANSWER: brian
WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING: 
TYPE YOUR ANSWER: abdul
WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING:
TYPE YOUR ANSWER: SOPHIA
WRONG ANSWER. ATTEMPT REMAINING:
NO MORE ATTEMPT REMAINING.
```